# Creating An Object From A Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, npm

Im just wondering how to create a JavaScript Object from a directory using node js.

Here's What I Mean:
If the root folder was "test" and the tree would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdSN9.png)
So the object structure would look like this:

```
{ test: { joe: {mama: "(file contents)"}, pp: {help: "very mature example\r\ni'm aware"} } }
```

edit: here's my attempt

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const root = "test";
const dir = __dirname + "\\" + root + "\\";
var currentFolder = dir.replace(__dirname + "\\", "");

var data = {};

const getFileSize = function (dirPath) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

  var length = 0;

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    length++;
  });

  return length;
};

fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((rootFile, rootIndex) => {
  fs.readdirSync(currentFolder).forEach((file, index) => {
    if (getFileSize(currentFolder) - 1 == index) {
      console.log(index, file, rootFile, currentFolder);
      currentFolder = currentFolder.replace(`\\file`, "");
      index++;
    }

    // if (file.includes("."))
    //   data[currentFolder + file] = fs.readFileSync(currentFolder + file, "utf8");
    // else currentFolder = currentFolder + file + "\\";
  });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: use ```fs.readdir``` or ```fs.readdirsync``` : https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Comment: yeh i tried using that, but i couldn't get it to work

Comment: update your question with your try.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh after hours of googling and stack overflow I found this:

```
    var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var walk = function (dir, done) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var i = 0;
    (function next() {
      var file = list[i++];
      if (!file) return done(null, results);
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function (err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            next();
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          next();
        }
      });
    })();
  });
};

var root = "test";
var data = {};

walk("test", function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  for (i in results) {
    data[
      results[i].replace(__dirname + "\\" + root + "\\", "")
    ] = fs.readFileSync(results[i], "utf8");
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```